# Can women in their menstruation cycle fast?

Tags: scripture, women, fasting, menstruation

Women can't (during their menstrual cycle) worship God because of them being impure, so does that also follow for fasting?

Comment: no. but not a must, all though they lose their stamina if they want to

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman do you have scriptural references for this? If so please present them.